# Where i can find my stock rom

Tags: samsung, stock-android, rom

Recently I bought a Chinese made android phone. Specifications of the phone is given [here](http://mywapbd.com). The phone has mediatek mtk6577 processor. I been thinking to install different ROM in my device. But, I can not find source to download this ROM. Is it possible to install google stock rom in this phone and where can I find this rom? How do I know which rom is compatible with my device?

Comment: Which one is your device?!? The link provided doesn't lead to a specific phone! Edit your question by adding the device name, Android version.

Comment: Knock-off brand Chinese devices rarely have any custom ROM choices, there just isn't sufficient demand for developers to do make any. And the manufacturers rarely even release the factory ROM image or abide by the GPL licensing and release source code. Sorry, but those devices are usually "as is" and throw away when something goes wrong.

Comment: @acejavelin Not necessary. All those phones listed there have ROM, Xiaomi is a perfect example. The others also have stock ROM principaly read from a working phone. Micromax is a serious manufacturer.

Comment: @esQmo And I wouldn't count Xiaomi or Micromax as "knock-off" brands... I was referring to the no name clones that pumped out of China at an alarming rate. And since the OP didn't state the make model and gave a link with no info, I went worst case.

Answer (score 1):

For finding other ROMs, Google is your best friend. If you can't find anything with Google, chances are that there aren't any custom ROMs for the phone. Any ROM that is compatible with the device will ***specifically*** list the phone. If it is not listed, it is ***not*** safe to flash the ROM and may result in hard-bricking the phone forever.

As far as the stock ROM goes, Google is again your best friend. Many manufactures post the stock ROM on their website for just this reason, however, if it is not there, you can always take a nandroid backup of the phone which also captures the stock ROM, allowing you to flash back the stock ROM if you wish to do so.